# Interactive plot R within dplyr ggplot plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, r-plotly, ggplotly

I'd like to create an interactive chart based on a `dplyr` pipe that I've created.  I'm not entirely sure if this is doable but would be pretty amazing if it worked.
Here's the code. I'd basically like to have a drop down menu where I can filter the `rxid` based on available unique options (commented out).
I'd like to avoid shiny if possible, but i guess can use shiny if needed.

```
    drugname <- c('cipro', 'moxi','tazo')
    lhoabx %>%
      #filter (rxid %in% 'drugname' ) %>% (drop down menu here?)
      group_by (locationid, month) %>%
      summarise (totaldot = sum(as.numeric(dot))) %>%
      right_join(pdays.summary, by = c('locationid', 'month')) %>%
      mutate (totaldot = case_when( is.na(totaldot) ~ 0
                                    ,TRUE ~ totaldot )) %>%
      mutate(dot1000 = totaldot/totalpdays * 1000) %>%
      ggplot (., aes(x = month, y = dot1000)) + 
      geom_line(aes(linetype = locationid))
```

Comment: How were you planning to make the chart interactive without using Shiny?

Comment: Yeah, was wondering if there was a way to do this without shiny. Was hoping to share this w somebody using powerbi

Comment: try the "manipulate" package. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200551906-Interactive-Plotting-with-Manipulate

Comment: the `crosstalk` package may be helpful if you use plotly: https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/